# Create second wireless network isolated from existing wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, gateway

Is there any device (router) where the WAN is delivered as a wireless signal?

internet<== Router1 ==>Wireless1<== Router2 ==> Wireless2

This is to create an isolated network (Wireless2) separate from the main one (Wireless1)?
so people connected to Router1 (Wireless1) has no access to Wireless2 and the devices connected to it.

I needed such setup because I have wireless internet shared with other people, and I do not have access to the main router (it is for the people I share the house with and they not like to change anything). So I need to have my network in private isolated network.

Now I can achieve easily with 2 devices one to receive (bridge mode) and the other is a typical wireless router, but I was thinking of a simpler solution (one device)

Comment: To clarify, you would like two separate wireless networks that can both access the internet but not each other?  Is one for guests?

Comment: I updated my question, hope it's clearer now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many domestic routers support the idea of a guest wireless network which is isolated from the main wireless/wired network but can still access the internet.  The Netgear WNDR3700 for example (this is not a recommendation, just an example).  It has a separate SSID, with separate IP addressing and security method.

It is almost always described as a "guest network" so this will help in your research.

**Update in response to additional information in question**

@jhcaiced has suggested openwrt, and [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com) is another option.  However, this doesn't provide all that you want.  With client mode in dd-wrt, the your wireless router acts as client to the AP.  You can then form a new network with the LAN ports.  However, you can't reuse the wireless interface on the router as an AP for the new network.  In order to do this, you are going to need two radios.  This could either be in the form of a second AP that you plug into the router active as client, or if the situation allows ityou could use a wireless router with a dual-band router that supports dd-wrt.

These come with two radios built in.  You could use one to connect to the existing network, and the other to create a new network isolated from the main one.  The difficulty here is that dual band routers usually have 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz radios.  If you used the 2.4ghz to connect to the current AP, then all your devices would need to support 5ghz.  If the existing AP supports 5Ghz, then this solution would work for you.

Comment: +1 The term "guest network" in home wifi routers means exactly this. The guest network is a different SSID and the router doesn't let devices on the guest network do anything but talk to the WAN port.

Comment: I forgot to add, you also see this as "wireless isolation" on some routers. The WNDR3700 has both. A guest network as an SSID, and wireless isolation that can be turned on for your regular SSID.

Comment: thank :) but does it work if my WAN is only a wireless signal? I explained more in my question!

Answer (score 1):

Try finding a router that can run something like openwrt.org, once you have openwrt installed on your router, you can configure the WAN side of your connection to be on a wireless client instead of the Ethernet Port of your router.

Check their list of supported devices:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

Comment: can I run Client and a router (receive wireless internet and resend it behind a a gateway/NAT) on the same device with this firmware?

Comment: You can separate the wireless interface and run it as client to receive the signal, then use the LAN/WAN ethernet ports to send your signal for your LAN. I have seen some routers which have a second wifi radio so you could use it as a WiFi AP but it depends on the hardware you have.